# How to efficiently evaluate a whole Python list of functions element-wise?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, function, numpy

Let's say I have a list of three functions:

```
f_list = [f1,f2,f3]
```

and an array of values, where each function should be evaluated

```
values = numpy.array([1,2,3])
```

such that I get f1(1), f2(2) and f3(3).

One way to do that is of course looping over the functions:

```
for i in range(3):
    print(f_list[i](values[i])
```

Is there a more efficient way to do that? Something similar to numpy array operations, where I can pass all values at once to get an array of function evaluations? 
As far as I know I cannot store functions in a numpy array, can I?

In my case I have a very large 2D-list of scipy interpolation (interp1d) functions (or call objects), which takes a long time to evaluate when looping over both axes.

Comment: I think you want to use `map`, although it's not very efficient with numpy. There is also the vectorize decorator: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

Comment: Are you sure your program takes a long time because of unoptimized loops as opposed to the unavoidable function calls themself?

Comment: "As far as I know I cannot store functions in a numpy array, can I?" You can store anything in a numpy array; but if it's not native to numpy, it gets `dtype=object` and you get scarce if any speed benefit from numpy (though you can still use the advanced manipulation functions). I'd probably just do `y = [f(x) for f, x in zip(f_list, values)]` or similar - same speed like your code, but a bit more readable to me

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python's inbuilt zip() [ or maybe izip() ] function. You would still need a loop though.

Comment: You can store anything in a numpy array, functions are just objects. If the functions are the same thing with different parameters (as you mentioned they're interpolation). Then you just need to store the parameters in arrays and pass everything to a single function. Usually it does the job.

Comment: It will be easier to help if you specify more precisely the functions,the data and their sizes.

Answer (score 4):

For *arbitrary* Python functions, a Python-level loop is unavoidable. One way is via a list comprehension:

```
f_list = [f1,f2,f3]
values = np.array([1,2,3])
res = np.array([func(val) for func, val in zip(f_list, values)])
```

Remember NumPy isn't a higher order function tool to convert normal functions into vectorised ones. Even [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) is little more than a Python-level loop. To vectorise your calculation, you will need to consider each function in turn and write some logic, if indeed it is possible to vectorise.

Answer (score -3):

If they are in order this code will work:

```
def a ( parameter ):
  print ( parameter )
def b ( parameter ):
  print ( parameter )
def c ( parameter ):
  print ( parameter )


f_list = [a, b, c]
v_list = [1, 2, 3]

for index, function in enumerate ( f_list ):
    function ( v_list [ index ] )
```

Comment: How is this any different than the solution given by OP? And it definitely does not accomplish what he/she has asked for